# Upload images on mysql

Tags: mysql, image, jsp, social-networking

I am working on a social networking site and i would like some help. I want the users of the site to upload images on mysql database. (I am using jsp pages). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can, although it's generally a bad idea.

It's better to store the images somewhere on your server and store the image's path in the database instead, where you can save it along with other data (e.g. information regarding the uploading user).

If you insist, store it using this type:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

[Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/)'s an example.